# Material2 navbar / sidebar misbehaving

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular5

I have HTML like so:

```html
  <mat-sidenav-container>

      <mat-sidenav #sidenav [(opened)]="opened">
        Start
      </mat-sidenav>

      <mat-sidenav-content>
        <div>
          <div fxLayout="row">
              .... my content here
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-sidenav-content>

  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

my CSS is pretty non-existent, but we have this:

```
.mat-sidenav {
  width: 400px;
}
```

the problem is that when the sidenav/sidebar opens, it covers up the inner content instead of moving the inner content over. For example:

*Sidebar closed*

[image]

*Sidebar opened*

[image]

What I would like to do, is invoke what should be the normal behavior of not covering up content but just shrinking and moving the content to the right.

Anyone know why it's not working as expected? Another question I have is how to prevent the inner content from being dark - I'd rather it just remain light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use:

```
@Input()
mode: 'over' | 'push' | 'side'
```

in the `mat-sidenav` selector, setting `mode="side"`